# How to add a widget to a ListView to scroll with items, but also be visible when the ListView's adapter is empty

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android

I have a `ListView` and a widget. I want the widget to be always on the top of `ListView`, and it should be able to scroll with the items but when there is no items in adapter it should still be visible. This is how it doesn't scroll:

[image]

[image]

The layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_togle_empty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="toggle empty"
            />


    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_test"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"


                />
        <ViewStub
                android:id="@+id/empty_layout"
                android:layout="@layout/empty"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The code for the activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    private ListView v;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
         v = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_test);
        View empty = findViewById(R.id.empty_layout);
        v.setEmptyView(empty);
        final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter();
        v.setAdapter(adapter);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_togle_empty);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                adapter.togleEmpty();
            }
        });
    }

    private  class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
       boolean empty = false;
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return empty ? 0 : 50;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return new Object();
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            TextView v =  new TextView(MyActivity.this);
            v.setText("STRING");
            return v;
        }


        public void togleEmpty() {
            empty = !empty;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I had one more idea, add the widget as header, but it disappears when the `ListView` is empty. How can I achieve the result I want?

Comment: It is EditText. I use it to filter the ListView. It is something like search input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            if (i == 0) { return custom_widget_view; }
        }
```

Comment: with this list will never be empty

Comment: Ok, I have a question, you want to put the widget on the top of list view, so can we just set it to the first item of the listView (you want it scrolling with items too, so it should be in listView)?

Comment: As you can see i have a custom layout for empty list, so if i put the widget as first position, the list will never be empty, and i don't want to handle it checking (getCount()==1) myself. Also i don't want to have 2 viewTypes in my addapter;

Comment: also the widget is filtering the list so the code would be really awfull

Comment: yesterday I had the same problem again, and .... I did the similar thing, so I accepted the answer after 5 monnth :D

Comment: Good to know your make it yourself. :D